# XCode Objective-C projects crashing on start

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I added a directory with images to a perfectly working Cocoa Obj-C project. My code immediately started crashing on start with the below messages.
I am not using IB whatsoever.
I tried to make rename my sources directory then create a new project with the same name. It too immediately crashes on start with the same error.
Please advise.

Thank you

```
Unknown class IDDragTableView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.118 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDWebView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.118 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDWebView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.127 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class LNSSourceListView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.128 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class LNSSourceListColumn in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.164 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDTableView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.164 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDTableView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.165 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDTableView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.165 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDTableView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.165 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDTableView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.166 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDTableView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.166 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDTableView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.166 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDTableView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.167 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDWebView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.167 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDWebView in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.168 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class IDSMSCell in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.169 BackupAssistant[33519:303] Unknown class CircleImageCell in Interface Builder file at path /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BackupAssistant-galyvxwzpdltaherqlqcobfokqbc/Build/Products/Debug/BackupAssistant.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2014-10-09 22:20:43.174 BackupAssistant[33519:303] An uncaught exception was raised
```

Comment: Why don't you try clearing the derived data for the project? 
Also check these out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591911/unknown-class-firstviewcontroller-in-interface-builder-file

Comment: Clearing the derived data helped. Thank you.

Comment: Remember to add an answer to your question if you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to delete the Derived data content.

1. Go to Xcode menu Windows -> Organizer.
   [image]
2. Delete the Derived data content (Remember to Quit Xcode)
   [image]