# Xcode 6.1: Unknown class x in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I came across an issue yesterday where I am not seeing any of my custom classes in Custom Class or Module fields under Identity Inspector. This causes my app to break every time I run it, with error such as 'Unknown class x in Interface Builder file'

I browsed through tens and twenties of solutions (literally!) that were available in Stack and other sites. But none of them is helping at all!

[Xcode 6 Strange Bug: Unknown class in Interface Builder file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file)

["Unknown class <MyClass> in Interface Builder file" error at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime)

[Unknown class FirstViewController in Interface Builder file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591911/unknown-class-firstviewcontroller-in-interface-builder-file)

https://parse.com/questions/using-pfloginviewcontroller-and-pfsignupviewcontroller-with-storyboarding-throws-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file-error

My learning has halted since yesterday due to small sh*** issue, has anybody encountered and resolved this issue before, please advise!

I also thought to re-install xcode but when I saw it was ~2.5G size, I again decided to give it a try and came to Stack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I forgot post how I could fix this issue.

Actually, it appeared to be a silly fix but I think it has to do with links. I simply changed the project folder location with a different name. I chose a folder name other than "iOS". Then it worked.

Hope it might help others.

Thanks

Comment: oh my god, this funny answer really helped. Had the same problem with Xcode 7 beta, tried a lot of possible solutions, but the problem kept repeating until I changed the project folder. 
Funny bug)) 
@Guru appreciate  your resourcefulness