# Unknown class _TtC8<appName>20MasterViewController in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I got this error despite doing the whole project programmatically. The app still works fine, and I never got the error until I started playing around with the app's AppDelegate `application()` function. Here's relevant code for that file:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FirstViewController())
    ...
    return true
}
```

Relevant parts in Xcode terminal:

```
Unknown class _TtC8<appName>20MasterViewController in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class _TtC8<appName>20DetailViewController in Interface Builder file.
```

All other similar errors ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591911/unknown-class-firstviewcontroller-in-interface-builder-file)) do not have the `_TtC8` part. I cannot find where this is coming from, "Find in workspace..." for "_TtC8" returned nothing.

What I've tried so far:

- Resetting content and setting in simulator
- Deleting app from simulator

Both did nothing to the error.

I know this error is related to the storyboard, so is there a way to run the application without the storyboard, since I haven't used it and won't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing your main interface entry in General of project settings if you want a custom window and rootVC.

[image]

Comment: Wow. That was way too easy. Thanks.